# Windows 7 randomly reboots on startup logo animation, but once booted it's perfectly fine

Tags: windows-7, boot, crash

I've been having this problem lately where Windows 7 will randomly reboot when it's starting up (only on the Windows logo animation over the black screen), however whenever I get past that screen everything runs perfectly fine. Even playing graphically intensive games for hours on end the computer doesn't crash or anything.

Whenever it crashes on startup it reboots and goes to the system recovery screen. I'm always getting a successful POST beep. Also it only happens after I completely shut down the computer and turn it back on. If I choose to restart it's fine.

What I've done:

chkdsk -> Ran successfully on the system SSD, no errors.

sfc -> Ran successfully, found nothing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the boot log and reviewed to see what/when the cause is? http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/monitor-windows-7-boot-logs-with-the-help-of-msconfig/

Comment: Hmm it doesn't look like it's writing anything to the bootlog on an unsuccessful boot. Also on further observation it gets further into the boot process every time I hit the power reset, but once I completely shut down that's all gone.

Comment: For some reason Windows installed the bootloader on my data drive instead of my SSD. I don't think that would cause this problem to happen all of the sudden but I'm going to try fixing that first...

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that:

1. For MBR disk - you have an active partition.
2. For GPT disk - you have EFI System partition + MS Reserved partition.

Then simply:

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s Z:
```

Z: is mapped to system partition (use diskpart.exe or mountvol.exe for mapping).

For MBR disk additionally:

```
bootsect /nt60 Z: /force /mbr
```

Note: it can be that c: is also the active partition on MBR disk. On GPT disk there is always a separate EFI System Partition!